# I need a regular expression for prices that must have a positive number then two decimal places. However, it cannot be zero dollars

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for prices that must have a positive number then two decimal places. However, it cannot be zero dollars Example 0.00 is wrong.

```
 if(preg_match("~^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$~",$userPrice))
```

Comment: Which language are you using ? can it be 0.01 ?

Comment: I am using PHP sorry. yes it can b 0.01 but not 0.00

Comment: I've updated my answer. To make it simple,first you need to check if the price is 0.00 , then check if it's a valid price (2 decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can valid it with this full regex way:

```
\A(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|0\.(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9]))\z
```

if the decimal digits are not optional:

```
\A(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}|0\.(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9]))\z
```

An other possible way consists to use `is_float` and to test if the variable is not equal to zero. However this way doesn't check the format.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
$userPrice = "0.00";

if (!preg_match('/0\.00/im', $userPrice)) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/i', $userPrice)){

        echo "valid price";
    }
}else{
    echo "Invalid Price";
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rSLpkf)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$|^0\.(?:[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

---

```
if (preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$|^0\.(?:[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/', $userPrice))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this `^ [0-9]*[1-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$`